# HAPI - How to allow processing of a message type with only 1 component in MSH-9

Tags: java, validation, parsing, hapi

I am building an application that interfaces with a system that sends message types of just ZPM for inventory-type transactions.  It also sends billing transactions which are of type DFT^P03 and my system is more than happy to process those.  When it receives a ZPM message however, the default pipe parser absolutely explodes and throws the following exception :

```
ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception: Can't determine message structure from MSH-9: ZPM HINT: there are only 1 of 3 components present
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.PipeParser.getStructure(PipeParser.java:186)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.PipeParser.doParse(PipeParser.java:223)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.GenericParser.doParse(GenericParser.java:245)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:212)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.GenericParser.parse(GenericParser.java:253)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.protocol.impl.ApplicationRouterImpl.processMessage(ApplicationRouterImpl.java:138)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.protocol.impl.ApplicationRouterImpl.processMessage(ApplicationRouterImpl.java:105)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.Responder.processMessage(Responder.java:91)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.Receiver$Grunt.run(Receiver.java:127)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am able to work around this problem by custom mapping our ZPM messages to DFT_P03 but this is a deployment step I would like to eliminate.  Furthermore, inventory messages are NOT a financial transaction so this is extremely hacky.  This is how I initialize my HAPI context :

```
ModelClassFactory cmf = new 
CustomModelClassFactory("com.something.some_lib.hl7.custommodel");

MinLowerLayerProtocol mllp = new MinLowerLayerProtocol();
mllp.setCharset(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());

hapiContext = new DefaultHapiContext();
hapiContext.setValidationContext(ValidationContextFactory.noValidation());
hapiContext.getPipeParser()
    .getParserConfiguration()
    .setUnexpectedSegmentBehaviour(
        UnexpectedSegmentBehaviourEnum.ADD_INLINE);
hapiContext.setModelClassFactory(cmf);
hapiContext.setLowerLayerProtocol(mllp);
```

Is there a way for these messages to be allowed through?

Comment: Any ideas on this?  I have created a ZPM^ZPM message class and if i could somehow provide a custom extension of PipeParser that taps into the message before parsing and changes MSH-9 to ZPM^ZPM that would fix the problem!